# can not rebuild aec model data for forge viewer model (NWC)

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to use below code for rebuilding aec model data and I have nwc model

```
      const aecdata = Autodesk.AEC.AecModelData.computeLevels(levels, viewer.model);
```

I found this code part from below link. But, when I try to use computeLevels function I get the error - "AecModelData.js:424 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myData')". What can be the problem?

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc

Comment: when you called this method, is viewer.model with valid value? I doubt it is null, or undefined.. In the first line of computeLevels, it will get model.myData.placementWithOffset, if model is null/undefined, it will throw the error

Comment: I have managed to use computeLevels successfully, but it is running so slowly. When I tried to compute levels by using this method, viewer waits 7-8 minutes to be opened fully and the levels are filled after this time. Is there any way to speed up this process?

Comment: Are you using SVF or SVF2? I think with SVF2, the loading (opening model) performance should be much better. As to performance of computeLevels , probably you included the loading time.. If it is slow after model has been loaded, please let us know

Comment: Using SVF2 gives much better performance results, but it still waits 9-10 seconds. Is there another way to minimize this duration?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Could you clarify the question? Do you mean 9-10 seconds is still slow? :) How fast you expect to have? Note: even with desktop software, 9-10 seconds may defeat many of them. Probably you are talking about some a context, I'd be interested in to hear.

Comment: or you meant by navigating the model (zoom/pan/orbit etc)?

Comment: Let me try to summarize my work. I added some sensor points on my viewer and when I push the points, I am trying to cut levels to focus on the place of sensors. So, waiting 9-10 seconds while I am computing the levels is not efficient for usability. I hope I could explain my concern successfully.

Comment: thank you for the elaboration. Please bear with me further confirming: if this slowness comes from Autodesk.AEC.AecModelData.computeLevels, or when you switch levels with the dialog (Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension)? While you mentioned [cut levels], are you using LevelsExtension to switch (you meant by cut), or your own logic to cut?

Comment: in the same time, I am also checking with the author Eason to have his comments

Comment: I am using the steps that are described below link. And, when I debug the system, realized that system waits at computeLevels.                                     https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc

Comment: In addition, I am using below code for cutting levels, but before this code part I am computing levels as mentinoed above.

Comment: const pMin = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 1, (currentLevel.elevation - currentLevel.height));
        const pMax = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, -1, -(levelAfter.elevation - levelAfter.height ));
        viewer.setCutPlanes([pMin, pMax]);